# Access calling object from Javascript method

Tags: javascript, this

In JavaScript, for an anonymous function defined inside the object, the `this` keyword refers to the object itself. However, when the function is defined outside the object scope, `this` refers to the window object, example:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this)
}

let A = {
  att: foo(),
  att2: "bla"
}

A.foo();
```

[EDIT]: I made a mistake in the original code, I meant to call the function as A.att() (and I am obliged to keep att: foo(). My code is basically the following:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this)
}

let A = {
  att: foo(),
  att2: "bla"
}

A.att();
```

The output here is object Window, and not the object that I want to access, which is A. And I can't change A, so how can I access A from foo()?

Comment: `A.att` is `undefined`.

Comment: I created a snippet for you. You can see it executes foo() when assigned to att. A.foo() does not exist, A.att  does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A function's `this` keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript compared to other languages. It also has some differences between strict mode and non-strict mode. In most cases, the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called.

To manipulate the `this` object by yourself you can use the JS methods `call`, `apply` & `bind`.

Lets demonstrate each with example:

**Function.prototype.call()**

Detailed info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this)
}

var A = {
  att: foo,
  att2: "bla"
}

foo.call(A);
```

**Function.prototype.apply()**

Detailed info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this)
}

var A = {
  att: foo,
  att2: "bla"
}

foo.apply(A);
```

**Function.prototype.bind()**

Detailed info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this)
}

var A = {
  att: foo,
  att2: "bla"
}

var x = foo.bind(A);
x();
```

Answer (score 0):

> In JavaScript, for an anonymous function defined inside the object, the `this` keyword refers to the object itself. However, when the function is defined outside the object scope, `this` refers to the window object

No. Where the function is defined is irrelevant. It is how a function is called that determines the value of `this`.

> The output here is object Window, and not the object that I want to access, which is A.

That is because you are calling `foo()` and then assigning the return value to `att`. `this` is `window` because you aren't calling `foo()` with any context.

Later you call `A.foo();` which throws an error because `A.foo()` is `undefined`.

Change: `att: foo()` to `att: foo` so you assign the function instead of calling it, and change `A.foo()` to `A.att()`

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this)
}

let A = {
  att: foo,
  att2: "bla"
}

A.att();
```

Comment: Thanks! I had already meant calling A.att(), but it was a typo of mine. This works, but I can't change A, and its att is defined as att: foo(), not att: foo. In my case, the caller becomes the window object.

Comment: @RawanMoukalled — If you can't change `A`, then you can't fix the problem. The value of `this` depends on how the function is called, and it is currently as part of the code for defining `A`.

Answer (score -1):

I would say I'm not agree with the answer because the question here is how to get the this (object) from where I'm calling the function, that is actually the Object A. I would prefer to bind the Object function instead to bind the Object directly to the global function. See the example below is binding A as the this object for B. In this situation I would be available to do this with any number of Objects without have to affect the original function.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this)
}

let A = {
  att: foo,
  att2: "From A"
}


let B = {
  att: foo,
  att2: "From B"
}

B.att = B.att.bind(A)

A.att();
B.att()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function foo() {
  console.log(this)
}

let A = {
  att: foo(),
  att2: "bla"
}

foo.call(A); //It will return Object A
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.